# How to move data across tables with django?

Tags: python, database, django, relational-database, cascade

Say I have three tables A, B, and C.  A is the active table, B has a one2one relationship with A, and C is an archive table to store old A data.  So in django I want to move a piece of data from A to C while being able to retain the one2one relationship with B.

So how can I do this?

Should I just copy the data to C, delete the data in A? How can I maintain the relationship with the data with B? Is this done with a one2one with C and B?  Does this mean I would have to key columns in B?  And if I delete from A does django cascade delete in B?

Or is there a whole different way of moving around data from table to table?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming A,B,C are 3 models declared in your app, you can simply make A and C have similar fields, and then copy the data from A to C, including the fkey field to B.

When you call delete in Django, it emulates the SQL constraint `ON DELETE CASCADE`, see https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.3/ref/models/querysets/#delete for more details.